# <li> how to set last item in navbar to the right

Tags: html, css

How to set last `<li>` element in navbar to the right?
Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Rozwiń nawigację</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> STRONA GŁÓWNA</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="panele.html">Panele podłogowe</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="wkrety.html">Wkręty i impregnaty</a></li>
    
  <li> <a href="test.pdf" download="Katalog produktów Drew-Holz"> KATALOG PRODUKTÓW
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#FF0000"> </i></a></li>
   </ul>

 
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS pseudo element `:last-of-type` will (amazingly) only effect the last of that type of element.

```css
    ul li:last-of-type {
        text-align:right;
    }
```

```html
#<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="panele.html">Panele podłogowe</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="wkrety.html">Wkręty i impregnaty</a></li>
    
  <li> <a href="test.pdf" download="Katalog produktów Drew-Holz"> KATALOG PRODUKTÓW
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#FF0000"> </i></a></li>
   </ul>
 
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

OR, if you only wish the inner content to be moved to the right rather than the bullet point itself you can do this:

Because all the contents of your `<li>` is wrapped in an anchor tag, you can style that anchor tag to do what you need.

```css
    ul li:last-of-type > a {
        display: block;
        text-align:right;
    }
```

```html
#<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="panele.html">Panele podłogowe</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="wkrety.html">Wkręty i impregnaty</a></li>
    
  <li><a href="test.pdf" download="Katalog produktów Drew-Holz"> KATALOG PRODUKTÓW
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#FF0000"> </i></a></li>
   </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`Like you said you wanted to set the last `<li>` item to right.
What i have done here is i made a parent class named `.sticky` and i put inside the `<li>` elements. I set `.sticky` to `displa:flex` and `justify-content: flex-end;` so all `<li>` elemts will be set to the end of the page.
and last part, i did `li:last-child` so i selected the 3rd `<li>` element and set it to `margin-left: auto;`.as you can see the results. Goal is achived.
Hope you found your answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .sticky {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }
        li:last-child {
           margin-left: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="sticky">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Martin glad i could help you. Please accept my answer so others can see it. Thanks.

Comment: Jeet, ok, I will accept your answer if you will accept my answer `;-)`

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: [I mean here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64277904/3536236)

Comment: So why did you asked the question when you had the answer ? Thanks man i'm good.

Comment: I asked you to clarify your answer, because code only answers are rarely very useful, and while your answer is useful there was no explanation as to *why* it was useful. It's called "constructive feedback", to help peers improve their answers to help Stack Overflow be more useful for all of us `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `margin-left: auto;` to the last element. There is a bootstrap utility class `class="ml-auto"`. This will push the element to the right.

For example,

```
<li class="ml-auto"></li>
```

Comment: margin-left:auto won't do anything on the `li` element.

Comment: I guess bootstrap is being used here? If so ml-auto perfectly works. Check code [here](https://codepen.io/shamsad-anam/pen/LYZEeyr)

Comment: Yes, it is bootstrap. I'm checking all answers. All of them are probably great but in my code no-one works

Comment: If you could make a [pen](https://codepen.io/) , I think it will be much clear on why it does not work in your case. Just copy paste your code in codepen.

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/877d2623 Is pastebin OK? Thank you for your time and help

Comment: First of all you are using a very old version of Bootstrap. That's why my solution is not working. Is there any reason for not using the latest [Bootstrap 4.5](https://getbootstrap.com/)? I highly recommend you to use the latest version. Because the latest version uses flexbox to align stuff and the old one is using floats. Floats are discouraged nowadays. Flexbox is much easier to align stuff and it very powerful and [all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3Aflex%3B) supports it. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to address the last child element of something specific. In this case it selects the first child element of its parent counted from the last one.

```css
ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
        text-align:right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="panele.html">Panele podłogowe</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="wkrety.html">Wkręty i impregnaty</a></li>
    
  <li> <a href="test.pdf" download="Katalog produktów Drew-Holz"> KATALOG PRODUKTÓW
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#FF0000"> </i></a></li>
   </ul>
 
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: I must admit that that `nth-last-child(n)` is a very over-engineered answer to a simple `last-of-type` requirement

Comment: It definetly is for this case, im pretty sure there are specific cases where it is the better solution cause it offers more control if i dont mix up anything, so i thought it wont hurt to give it as an alternative right? Your answer is what i would have done too for this specific case here :)